# Configuring Eclipse to use lldb in M2 Mac

Tags: eclipse, lldb

I'm trying to configure eclipse for debugging Fortran projects via lldb in M2 Macbook pro.

I have installed lldb and I can execute lldb in the terminal, but when I put lldb information in eclipse debug configurations and try to debug my project, eclipse returned an error message: "Problem Occurred 'Launching xx.x' has encountered a problem. Could not determine GDB version using command: lldb --version"

I assume this is because I put lldb information on the GDB-version debugging. However, I could not figure it out.

Is there anybody experienced this before?

I appreciate your helps!

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask] and [mre]. What exactly and where exactly you put as "lldb information"?

Comment: Did you read https://discourse.llvm.org/t/can-window-eclipse-use-lldb-debug/66226 ? This is just a random quick web search hit, I do not personally use Eclipse or lldb.